# Flash[:error] is not shown when user is redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am implementing in Ruby on Rails, and when a user filled in something wrong, or something wrong is happened, the user has to go back to the previous page, and with a correct error message. I tried to do this with:

```
redirect_to 'javascript:history.go(-1)', flash.now[:error] =>"Something went wrong"
```

Now, this goes back to the previous page, but this without the flash error? Does someone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**  I tried :

```
 redirect_to 'match', :notice => 'Something went wrong'
```

Match is the previous page, but now I get an error from my browser:

```
No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
```

Comment: Write `render :js def_name.js.erb` instead of `redirect_to` there you write javascript you want! that will work..!!

Comment: So where do I put this javascript? Can you give the code per haps? Thanks already

Comment: have you set up a route to your 'match'-page? Then `redirect_to match_url ...`

Answer (score 3):

You can't mix Javascript and Ruby this way. Your Javascript call does not make any side-server action, so your ruby code is never executed.

[default error handling](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) of Ruby on Rails is quite convenient and if you can, it's better to use it.

If you really cannot use it, you'll have to choose between Ruby and Javascript for this matter. The recommended way is the Ruby way :

```
redirect_to user_path(@user), :notice =>"The user was successfully created"
```

see [this post](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/12/20/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-set-flash-in-redirect_to) of Ryan for more detail. I am not sure if this is possible in Javascript, because you'll have to pass error information to the previous page without reloading it.

Comment: I already looked at this post, but the problem is that the user has to select some items in a dropdown to let the system read in a CSV-file. So it doesn't really have an object like @user...

Comment: you can use path without objet, in rails, like users_path, for instance. Do not forget to display the flash message in your layout see [this post](http://pupeno.com/2009/11/19/ensuring-the-displaying-of-flash-messages-in-ruby-on-rails/) for more details

Comment: Ok, i did this your way:   redirect_to match_path, :notice =>"The user was successfully created", and then in my view "match":  <% if flash[:notice] -%>
  <p class='notice'><%=h flash[:notice] %></p>
<% end -%>
But now I got the error: undefined local variable or method `match_path' for #. What's wrong with this?

Comment: you should check your [routing system](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). If it's an index page, it should be "matches_path".

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
redirect_to :back, :flash => {:error => "Error"}
```

Comment: @Ruben are you displaying content of flash[:error] in your layout file ?

Comment: So directly in my views you mean? No i do not

Answer (score 1):

`flash.now` triggers the flash in the same rendering sequence. After a redirect you are on a newly rendered page and therefor your shouldn't use `flash.now` but something like

```
redirect_to :back, error: 'Something went wrong'
```